“CharacterPalette.app wants to download the font”
Prompt “CharacterPalette.app wants to download the font [insert some font name here]” appears. Pressing the “Skip” button causes it to appear again infinitely, and Sonoma gets very slow to respond. The app is not running per Activity Monitor, and quitting all other apps or relaunching Finder doesn’t solve the problem, only a hard reboot does. Is that a known bug?


That is a “simplified Chinese” font. I would bet that macOS needs or thinks it needs the font to continue

I know what that font is. :) The message also appeared with many other CJK fonts, including Japanese. I don’t think the exact fonts is a relevant part of the question.

The important part was"...that macOS needs..." So this is not spy/malware it is most likely a part of macOS. And macOS tells the characterpallette.app to ask for the font. Download the fonts, they won't take up significant space on your storage and besides Apple Insists ;-)

Apple really needs to stop with all the fonts.

It never appeared before and never appeared again after the reboot. Interesting. Did not install major OS updates recently either.
